# DAX measure: "Weighted distribution %"

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I hope you can help me with a complicated problem.
I am trying to make a measure which calculate the “weighted distribution %” of a product.

The business definition for this calculation is:

“In a customer Chain we have a number of customers which buys a specific product(selected). We need to find out how much volume these “BUYING customers” buys of the whole PRODUCT GROUP (which this product belongs to) and compare it to the volume of the PRODUCT GROUP bought by ALL customers in the Customer Chain.”

**Example (calculation):**

Product (selected)=”Product 1”

Number of ALL Customers in “Chain 1” = 18

Volume of PRODUCT GROUP bought by ALL customers in chain = 10.915

Number of BUYING customers in “Chain 1” (who have bought “Product 1”) = 8

Volume of PRODUCT GROUP bought by BUYING customers in chain = 6.945

Calculation:

**Weighted distribution % =**
Volume (BUYING Customers in chain) / Volume (ALL Customers in chain) = 6.945 / 10.915 = 63,6%

**Example (Calculation setup in PBI):**

Now, my datamodel is this (simplified):
[image: Data model]

NOTE(just for info): you may ask why I make a customer count on both “D_Customer” and “F_SALES”, but that is because I can make a customer count on specific transaction dates I F_SALES, ande these I don’t have in D_CUSTOMERIf I set the the following filters:

Chain= “Chain 1”

Product=”Product 1”

I get the following table:

[image]

I then calculate the volume on the PRODUCT GROUP with the following measure

```
Volume (PRODUCT GROUP) = CALCULATE('F_SALES'[Volume];ALLEXCEPT('D_PRODUCT';'D_PRODUCT'[Product group]))
```

And add it to the table:

[image]

Now I have the “Volume (ALL Customers in chain)” part for my weighted distribution calculation.
[image]

My problem is how I make a measure, which shows the Volume for the BUYING customers only?

I have tried to make the following calculation, which brings me close:

```
Volume (BUYING Customers) = 
VAR BuyingCustomers_=CALCULATE([Number of Customers(F_SALES)];FILTER('F_SALES';NOT(ISBLANK('Sold to trade'[Customer ID])))) 
RETURN
SUMX(SUMMARIZE(D_Customer;D_Customer[Customer Chain];"volume";CALCULATE('F_SALE'[Volume];ALLEXCEPT('D_Product';'D_Product'[Product Group]);FILTER('F_SALE';NOT(ISBLANK(BuyingCustomers_)))));[volume])
```

Result:

[image]

But, as you can see, the volume doesn’t aggregate to “PRODUCT GROUP”-level ?

What I need is this:

[image]

Which will give me the measure necessary for my calculation:

[image]

Can anyone bring me the missing part?

It will be greatly appreciated.

Br,
JayJay0306